# trying to install oauth pecl extension

Tags: apache2, php, oauth

I'm trying to install the pecl oauth package with PHP 7.2 and don't know what I'm doing wrong. I ran this:

```
sudo pecl install oauth
```

and it seemed to work. It said this:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/20151012/oauth.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/oauth-2.0.2
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=oauth.so" to php.ini
```

I opened my php.ini file and tried all of these:

```
extension=oauth.so
extension=oauth
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/oauth.so
```

I restarted apache each time.

I ran php -m, phpinfo(), and get_loaded_extensions() each time and oauth doesn't show up.

I noticed this in the phpinfo():

extension_dir=/usr/lib/php/20170718

but pecl installed oauth into

/usr/lib/php/20151012

Could that be the problem? If so, why would pecl install it into a different folder? Could I just move the oauth.so file into the 20170718 folder?

Answer (score 7):

You may want to try this instead:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php-oauth
sudo service apache2 restart
```

It worked well for me, running Ubuntu 18.04, PHP 7.2.5.

Comment: If it doesn't work, add your PHP version `sudo apt-get install php7.4-oauth`